# GKTurnedBased Match, receiving an invitation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, game-center

I'm building a turned based game in iOS.
I have a custom UI and so far I can authenticate the user, find random matches, invite friends, and send data to and from the players.
My problem is this: When a player invites another player, the second player gets a push notification. The second player needs to go to the gamecenter to accept or decline the game and then come back. I have not found a way to create a custom GUI for this. The methods shown in Apple's APIs are deprecated ([GKTurnBasedEventHandler sharedTurnBasedEventHandler].delegate = self; | handleInviteFromGameCenter: | and so on) [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH15-SW8].

Can someone please point me to the right direction? I don't mind if it is Objective-c or Swift.

Thank you

UPDATE:

I created TurnBasedSkeleton (github.com/mhatzitaskos/TurnBasedSkeleton). This project aims to create a skeleton for any turn based game using GameCenter. As GameCenter seems to lack in documentation and tutorials, especially as far as turn based gaming is concerned, I decided to create this project to help others who might want to integrate GameCenter to their projects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following class below as of iOS 7 and later.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayerListener_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/GKLocalPlayerListener

Under the GKLocalPlayer object there is a method called registerListener and pass the NSObject you created that conforms to GKLocalPlayerListener.

Comment: I have done that. What I do not understand is how to register my class to listen for the invitation from another player? Which method, protocol or delegate do I need to connect to or implement? Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: Right so under [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer], there is a method called register listener that takes an NSObject that conforms to the GKLocalPlayerDelegate.

Comment: OK, I've already done that. So we have the following: "The GKLocalPlayerListener protocol inherits the methods from GKChallengeListener, GKInviteEventListener, and GKTurnBasedEventListener in order to handle multiple events.". Which method from all of these is called when the local player receives an invitation from another user? I would guess that he would receive a GKMatch and would reply with an ACCEPT or DECLINE message.

Comment: In iOS 6 it used to be this method "handleInviteFromGameCenter:" from the  GKTurnBasedEventHandlerDelegate protocol.